# JQuery loads but doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

was testing some JQuery things (i'm new to this) but i can't make jquery work!
First it worked two or three times and then it stopped working (pretty weird) so i changed a few things and now it doesn't work at all. JQuery and script.js load but doesn't seem to work

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sansita+One" />
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <title>Manuel Pepe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav-bar" class="nav-bar">
            <div id="container">
                <img id="nav-button" class="nav-button" src="imgs/menu.png" />
                <div id="nav-menu" class="nav-menu">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="front-page">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Manuel Pepe</h1>
                <h3>Test</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.css**

```
html{
position:relative;
height:100%;
background-color: #6E6E6E; 
}

#container{}

.nav-button{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    width: 32px;
    height: auto;
    z-index:1;
} 

.nav-menu{
    background-color:#424242;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 200px;
    height:100%;
}

.logo{
    position: relative;
    top:250px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 225px;
}

.logo h3, h1{
    text-align:center;
    font-family: Sansita One;
    color: #222;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
}

.logo h1{
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.logo h3{
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.hover-rotate:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  transform: rotate(-180deg);

}
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav-button").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hover-rotate");
    });
    $("#nav-button").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hover-rotate")
    })
});
```

Why isn't this working?

Also, is there any way to improve the JQuery code?

Comment: Do you see any console errors ?

Comment: Check console and source if jquery-2.1.4.min.js is really loaded.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? How did you test it?

Comment: It's not an Dynamic Html, then why you need late binding, directly in html tag itself.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sLbt7sgg/.  What browser are you testing as jQuery 2* only works on the newer ones.  With regards to anything you could change - move the scripts to before the end body tag and maybe use [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of mouseenter and leave (or cache your `$("#nav-button")` object if you want to keep them seperate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `$()` constructor instead of `$(document).ready(function(){...`:

```
$(function () {

   $("#nav-button").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).addClass("hover-rotate");
    });
    $("#nav-button").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("hover-rotate")
    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a timeout inside your javascript with a condition like

```
if (typeof jQuery != "undefined")
```

Comment: why timeout? how would he know when the page loads? use events instead of arbitrary timeouts

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine when I'm testing it. See this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v1t54urc/2/

Are you sure your jQuery is loaded? Also make sure your CSS is loaded correctly. Try to use the following code in the header to be sure:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

One more thing. Don't forget the ; at the end on the code, like this:

```
$("#nav-button").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover-rotate");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to ensure that JQuery is loading correctly:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

If you do the change and the web works, the old line can't find the "jquery-2.1.4.min.js" in the folder.